# New to python, stuck in room and can't add items to inventory

Tags: python

i'm doing an project, text based game and it tells what your you're in and what item but it's stuck there, i cant change rooms or add items to inventory, I tried putting in north and south still gives same you are in kitchen response and nothing happens when I try to add knife to inventory

```
user_instructions()

inventory_items = [] 
current_room = 'Kitchen'  
command = ''

while current_room != 'Bedroom':  
    user_status()
    command = input('Enter your next move.\n').lower()
    if command == 'take':
        item = input('What do you want to take? ').lower()
        if item in rooms[current_room] and ['item']:
            inventory_items.append(current_room['item'])
        else:
            print(f"There's no {item} here.")
    elif command in rooms[current_room]:
        current_room = rooms[current_room][command]
    else:
        print('Invalid command')
```

Comment: you always `.lower()`, so it can't start with `B`

Comment: `if item in rooms[current_room] and ['item']` this means that you check two conditions. the first one: item in rooms[rurrent_rrom], the second one ['item'] means that this newly created not assigned to any name list is not empty and in fact it's not (you placed string 'item' into it). but what for?

Comment: You should show the complete `rooms` datastructure to be able to get good answers. It appears that both items to be taken and directions to be traveled are possible objects within a room. What happens if somebody says they want to take 'north' while in the Kitchen. From what I can see here you will add a 'north' to their inventory.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things seems to be off with your code and you should consider a refactor. One thing is that it's begging for more context as some things are missing and this could turn out to be a "case of shooting in the dark" for anyone who would love to help.

1. It appears so that the dictionary to represent the different "rooms" and their connections is missing in your code snippet. Let's look at this dictionary as a start to make sense of the rest of the opinions. They are in key-value pair and you can easily move bwith keys of the dictionary this way. Also note that the keys are in lowercase:

   ```
   rooms = {
       'Kitchen': {
           'north': 'Living Room', 'items': ['knife', 'spoon']
       },
       'Living Room': {
           'south': 'Kitchen'
       }
   }
   ```

   I believe this dictionary will help us better to deal with moving from one point to another. Proceed to read the rest of the concerns.
2. I do think that it would be profitable and knowledge-acquiring to play with Lists & Dictionaries and know how you can iterate over them. So that, when you have a scenario of checking if the item is in the current room, you will be able to access the items key of the dictionary representing the current room. A good example is to use something like `if item in rooms[current_room]['items']` based on a proper declaration of rooms dictionary, which could be nested, instead of using what you used which is, `if item in rooms[current_room] and ['item']`.
3. Playing well with dictionaries and learning them will give you the knowledge to remove/delete from a dictionary. What I think is using something like `inventory_items.append(item)`, as well as `del rooms[current_room]['items']`, instead of `if item in rooms[current_room] and ['item']: inventory_items.append(current_room['item'])`
4. You should look at your code like a real object such as entering through a door and exiting. You will need to make sure that the exits for each room are represented correctly in the rooms dictionary for a player to move between rooms.

So, let's rewrite your code by first dealing with the declarations and proceeding from there.

```
def user_status():
    print('You are in the ' + current_room)
    print('Inventory:', inventory_items)


def user_instructions():
    print("Welcome to the game! You can move between rooms using the cardinal directions (north, south, east, west). You can also take items by typing 'take' and the name of the item. Type 'quit' to exit the game.\n")


rooms = {
    'Kitchen': {'north': 'Living Room', 'items': ['knife', 'spoon']},
    'Living Room': {'south': 'Kitchen'}
}

inventory_items = []
current_room = 'Kitchen'
command = ''

user_instructions()

while current_room != 'Bedroom':
    user_status()
    command = input('Enter your next move.\n').lower()
    if command == 'take':
        item = input('What do you want to take? ').lower()
        if item in rooms[current_room]['items']:
            inventory_items.append(item)
            rooms[current_room]['items'].remove(item)
            print(f"{item} has been added to your inventory.")
        else:
            print(f"There's no {item} here.")
    elif command in rooms[current_room]:
        current_room = rooms[current_room][command]
    elif command == 'quit':
        break
    else:
        print('Invalid command')

print('Game over.')
```

output:

```
Welcome to the game! You can move between rooms using the cardinal directions (north, south, east, west). You can also take items by typing 'take' and the name of the item. Type 'quit' to exit the game.

You are in the Kitchen
Inventory: []
Enter your next move.
north

You are in the Living Room
Inventory: []
Enter your next move.
items

Invalid command
You are in the Living Room
Inventory: []
Enter your next move.
south

You are in the Kitchen
Inventory: []
Enter your next move.
```

In this solution, you may still experience some error such as `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str`. I rather will prefer you fix it for your learning purpose. That error will be pointing to `print('You are in the ' + current_room)` or `print('Inventory:', inventory_items)`.

You can see you are able to move between keys in a dictionary. I do hope this has been informative for you and it can push your further in the Python quest.

Also you may learn to use 'pdb' library to see how your code is acting under the hood to fix errors or pains going forward.

Comment: If I may help you with HINT to the error, when a dictionary is defined with no `items`, then the error will flag a `TypeError` due to concatenation of `list` with `str`. If you define `items` for `Living Room:`, then you will not experience that error. Play around with it.